# Identity $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1+x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x}}\right)dx=-\frac{4}{3}.$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How I can prove that

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1+x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x}}\right)dx=-\frac{4}{3}.$$

The convergence I get it using an asymptotic expansion. I cannot divide it into two integrals, it will not converge.

I don't get good ideas to compute it.

Comment: Note that $^{1/4}\sqrt{x}=x^4$

Comment: Are you sure that the integral goes from $0$ to $\infty$, and not from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: From where did you get this integral? Are you sure there's no typo?

Comment: @LeBlanc I came up with this integral alone, its is both maple and wolfram that say it is equal to $-4/3.$

Comment: There's still a typo. A minus sign should be a plus instead.

Comment: What is $\sqrt[4]{1-x}$ for $x > 1$?

Comment: @MartinR Oh I see LeBlanc's point. I was thinking he wants a $+$ in the center. There is still a type. I am sorry.

Comment: @LeBlanc I didn't understand correctly, I see your point. Sorry about that.

Comment: @LeBlanc thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define$$f(y):=\int_0^y\left((1+x)^{-1/4}-x^{-1/4}\right)=\frac43\left[(1+y)^{3/4}-y^{3/4}-1\right].$$To evaluate $\lim_{y\to\infty}f(y)$, use a large-$y$ approximation:$$f(y)=\frac43\left[y^{3/4}\left((1+\tfrac1y)^{3/4}-1\right)-1\right]\approx\frac43\left[\frac34 y^{-1/4}-O(y^{-5/4})-1\right]\stackrel{y\to\infty}{\to}-\frac43.$$